# Css hover on image - load a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to do a CSS effect on hovering an image.

I'd like to show a div containing content like text when I hover on an image.

So I'd like to do something with this code:

```
<div id="image"><img src="image.png"/></div>

<div id="hover">Test message</div>
```

I have tried to hide the "hover" div in css display and on hover I tried to set the display to block, but its not working...:(

EDIT: I want the text on the image. When I hover the image it should get some opacity BUT the text should not recieve that opacity!

IS there any method to do this?

Comment: Can we see your javascript? also setting a http://jsfiddle.net/ would help...

Comment: The soultion should be without javascript?

Comment: Yeah it should be without Js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZQK/**

```
#hover {
    display: none;
}

#image:hover + #hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Just keep it simple, no need to change your markup.

---

**Update**

If you want to change opacity of image on mouse hover, then
**http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZQK/4/**

```
#hover {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

#image:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

#image:hover + #hover {
    display: block;
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Since you added a couple of more requirements to your initial question, now it requires a change in the original html markup.

I am assuming you are using `html5`, and if so, you should use the tags appropriated for your content's context:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" />
    <figcaption>Test message</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and the css

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

figure:hover img {
    opacity: .7;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/ZSZQK/7/)**

Comment: @Taboo Loco Updated answer for image opacity

Comment: Thank you it is working, however its kinda weird, as when I hover the mouse on the assumed place where the text should be, the text is not appearing and it kina flases.

Comment: @TabooLoco That happens when you hover the text (not the image), so I just moved the text behind. For a better fix, you will need to change your markup as TheBronx and James King sugested. See **http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZQK/5/**

Comment: The problem is now that the text also got opacity :S Is there any way to get rid of the opacity of the text? Or can you please show me an example of how should I change the markup?

Comment: @TabooLoco I am going off line. Will be back in 3-4 hours

Comment: @ Jose Rui Santos Okay please let me know when you are here. And thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ah this is awesome! Thank you man it works like a charm! However should I need to use "figure" tags to have this succeeded?

Comment: @TabooLoco No, you don't need `figure` tags for this to work. It also works with `div`. But you should take advantage of what `html5` offers you, and if you have figures with captions, then you should use `figure` and `figcaption` elements.

Comment: Okay thank you for you help. You have helped me a lot! You deserver  lots of +ups.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="image.png"/>
    <div class="hover">Test message</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    position:relative;
}

#image .hover {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

#image:hover .hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Basically what I did was:

- Moved text div inside `#image` div.
- Changed `id="hover"` to `class="hover"`
- Added `display:block` when `#image` is hovered and `display:none` if not.
- Some positioning rules, it's just a fast example, let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you it is actually working. Is there any way that on hover I can make the image's opacity to about 70% and place the text over the image?

Like the text would be placed on the opacity image when someone hovers the mouse over the image.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to do this, but if you want a CSS only approach, you would need to restructure your html to something like:

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="image.png"/>
    <div id="hover">Test message</div>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS hide the message by default:

```
#hover {display:none;}
```

Then show the message:

```
#image:hover #hover {display:block;}
```

Comment: Yes but if I want to add opacity to the image, the text also gets opacity :S

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript you can do like this :

1.Make the `#hover` `div` be on top of the image and set the `opacity:0`;

2.Than add this to the css :

```
    #hover:hover {
     opacity:1
     }
```

This should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution i found on google

```
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Untitled Document</title>
                </head>
                <style type="text/css">
                #mybox {
                width:80px;
                height:90px;
                float:left;
                background-color:#0F9;
                padding:10px;
                }
                .Imgdiv {
                width:80px;
                height:20px;
                margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; padding:0px;
                cursor:pointer;
                background-color:#39C;
                }
                #mybox .hiddenDiv {
                left:0px;
                display:none;
                z-index:100;
                width:80px;
                height:50px;
                margin:0px;
                background-color:#336;
                float:left;
                }
                #mybox:hover .hiddenDiv {
                display:block; top:0px; left:8px;
                }
                </style>
                <body>
                <div id="mybox">
                <div class="Imgdiv"></div>
                <div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
                </div>


                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello If I understand correctly you want something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp7bY6nYWTDmFXKSlP4TdCe5ghVQhbt85tQMS8dfZMEGw7QOXiLA">
    </div>
    <div id="text-wrapper">
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:102px;
    height:102px;
}

#text-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial,Tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;

    transition: height 1s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s; /* Opera */

}

#img-wrapper:hover + #text-wrapper{
    height:32px;
    width:102px;
}
```

The key to accomplish this is this css line:

```
#img-wrapper:hover + #text-wrapper{
```

What it actually does is "When I hover img-wrapper div do some stuff in text-wrapper div"

Check demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/A9pNg/1/