# Hide Div until hover on icon

Tags: html, css

I have hit a brick wall on this one, I am working on a website where I need to hide a DIV of extra content until the user hovers over an icon but I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried various different ways (>, + and ~) but I just cant get it to work.

HTML

```css
.fa-canapes-icon:hover .canapes-popup{
    display:block;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="canapes">
<p>Canapes <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-canapes-icon"></i></p>
<div class="canapes-popup">
<h1>Example Canape Menu</h1>
<p>This is a popular selection. We do of course have other options we are happy to discuss with you.<br>
Mini Yorkshires with Medium Roast Beef and Horseradish<br>
Satay Chicken Skewers with a Peanut Sauce<br>
Spicy Prawn with Mango<br>
Smoked Salmon &amp; Mascarpone crostini with Dill &amp; Lemon<br>
Mozzerella Pearls with Sun-blush tomatoes &amp; Fresh Basil (V)<br>
Honey and Sesame Coated Cocktail Sausages</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The page can be viewed [here](http://hh-testing.co.uk/monsterfoods/wedding-catering/) and it is the 'wedding package 3' with the canapes i icon that I am trying to add it onto.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which is the div you are trying to hide/show ? Is it this : `canapes-popup`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Css hover on image - load a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339182/css-hover-on-image-load-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is failing since `<i>` does NOT have any siblings; and your `<div>` of interest is a sibling to `<i>`'s parent. Therefore, you could do the following:

```
<p class="icon-container">Canapes <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-canapes-icon"></i></p>
```

And, add the following CSS:

```
.icon-container:hover + .canapes-popup {
    display: block;
}
```

It seems to be working. Let me know if it does for you too. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9637hsu/)

Comment: Awesome thank you! I am fairly new to html and css and this has helped massively.

Answer (score 1):

Your css would suggest that **.canapes-popup** is a child of **.fa-canapes-icon** looking at your html however this is not the case.

Have you tried the **adjacent sibling selector**. This allows you to select a an element that is directly after one specified.

For example you could try:

```
.fa-canapes-icon:hover + .canapes-popup{
    display:block;   
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The adjacent sibling selector won't work in this case as `.canapes-popup` is NOT an adjacent sibling of `.fa-canapes-icon`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display on hover of p because p and your div is nearby so use this css

```css
.canapes-popup{
    display:none;
    
}
p:hover + .canapes-popup{
    display:block;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="canapes">
<p>Canapes <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-canapes-icon"></i></p>
<div class="canapes-popup">
<h1>Example Canape Menu</h1>
<p>This is a popular selection. We do of course have other options we are happy to discuss with you.<br>
Mini Yorkshires with Medium Roast Beef and Horseradish<br>
Satay Chicken Skewers with a Peanut Sauce<br>
Spicy Prawn with Mango<br>
Smoked Salmon &amp; Mascarpone crostini with Dill &amp; Lemon<br>
Mozzerella Pearls with Sun-blush tomatoes &amp; Fresh Basil (V)<br>
Honey and Sesame Coated Cocktail Sausages</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:**

The manner in which you have your css selectors currently defined:

```
.fa-canapes-icon:hover .canapes-popup
```

...the popup element (`.canapes-popup`) would have to be *nested within the icon element* (`.fa-canapes-icon`) in order for this rule to apply as expected.

**The Solution:**

Apply a class to the containing `p` tag of the icon in question so that you can use it as a selector with the *[adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)* selector, e.g:

```
.canapes-icon:hover + .canapes-popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.canapes-icon:hover + .canapes-popup {
  display: block;
}

.canapes-popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="canapes">
  <p class="canapes-icon">Canapes <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-canapes-icon"></i></p>
  <div class="canapes-popup">
    <h1>Example Canape Menu</h1>
    <p>This is a popular selection. We do of course have other options we are happy to discuss with you.<br> Mini Yorkshires with Medium Roast Beef and Horseradish<br> Satay Chicken Skewers with a Peanut Sauce<br> Spicy Prawn with Mango<br> Smoked Salmon
      &amp; Mascarpone crostini with Dill &amp; Lemon<br> Mozzerella Pearls with Sun-blush tomatoes &amp; Fresh Basil (V)<br> Honey and Sesame Coated Cocktail Sausages</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[More on CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

Answer (score 0):

As `.fa-canapes-icon` is a child of its parent `<p>` (and `.canapes-popup` is a sibling of that `<p>`) we have no way of targeting `.canapes-popup` in relation to `.fa-canapes-icon`.

A much simpler solution would be to display the `.canapes-popup` on hover of its parent. This also has the affect of keeping the popup open when you move the mouse inside it.

E.G:

```css
.canapes-popup {
  display: none;
}

.canapes:hover .canapes-popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="canapes">
  <p>Canapes <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-canapes-icon"></i></p>
  <div class="canapes-popup">
    <h1>Example Canape Menu</h1>
    <p>This is a popular selection. We do of course have other options we are happy to discuss with you.<br> Mini Yorkshires with Medium Roast Beef and Horseradish<br> Satay Chicken Skewers with a Peanut Sauce<br> Spicy Prawn with Mango<br> Smoked Salmon
      &amp; Mascarpone crostini with Dill &amp; Lemon<br> Mozzerella Pearls with Sun-blush tomatoes &amp; Fresh Basil (V)<br> Honey and Sesame Coated Cocktail Sausages</p>
  </div>
</div>
```